# include html/css in HTML= statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Very new to jquery. I have a simple xml file that I am reading and displaying well in an html page. However one of my records in xml has an attribute that none of the others do. While all have a name and number, one has a name, name type and number.

I can read this data fine, but displaying it is proving tricky. All of the data are going into a css styled table (very well), but this additional attribute I want to create a line break for and display on a second line within the cell, but have all of the other records' cells remain one line.

You can see here what I am trying to do:

```js
function BuildContactHTML(contactName,contactNumber,contactSE){

// Check to see if their is a "type" attribute in the name field
if ((contactType) != undefined){
    contactTypeHTML = "<br /><span class="sub">(" + contactType + ")</span>";
}
else
{
    contactTypeHTML = "";
}

// Build HTML string and return
output = '';
output += '<tr>';
output += '<td class="left">'+ contactName + contactType +'</td>';
output += '<td class="phone">'+ contactNumber +'</td>';
output += '</tr>';
return output;
}
```

In the line "contactTypeHTML =" I want to add a line break then style the text with css then close the cell, so effectively I get the attribute under the name, in smaller type which the span class "sub" is handling. If I put these tags in the output string it makes a second line for all the records, but I just want it to affect the record that actually has an attribute, the rest have no text at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Again, I'm pretty new, so please keep it simple. I am under the impression I just have a syntax issue here.

Comment: Can you post up the final HTML of the table, perhaps with a screen shot showing how it looks in the browser?

Comment: I'm too new to post an image, the site won't let me!

Answer (score 1):

Undefined should be a string value, and you need the typeof operator around **contactType**

```
if (typeof(contactType) != "undefined"){}
```

the **typeof()** operator returns a string value, so you need to compare it to a string.

Your code is checking if contactType is not equal to an object that doesn't exist, so that will always return true as it's a double negative.

You also need to use single and double quotes on this line, not just doubles. You need to put the double quotes around "sub" inside single quotes.

```
contactTypeHTML = '<br /><span class="sub">(' + contactType + ')</span>';
```

Comment: I tried editing my code to what you've shown here, but I am getting the same error I have been, which says "missing ; before statement" and has an arrow that points to the "contactTypeHTML=" line in the if statement, in between the " & the line break tag.

I adapted this code from a sample that did work as written, but the attribute was on the same line as the name and merely made bold with the 'strong' tag.

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is **not** a function. It's an operator, similar to `void` and `+`.

Comment: typeof accepts a parameter, doesn't that make it a function? : typeof("hello world");